# Hiding image source

Tags: css

How can I host an image in this way:
https://card.psnprofiles.com/2/AGK111112.png

When I right click and look at image information its image size is hidden. Also I am not able to save the image.

I'm not interested in saving the image, just how can I host images like this?

Comment: It is not a PNG file. For one PNG files don't have animation. This is actually 2 PNG images with CSS keyframes animation applied to it. You can't save this as a PNG, but because the whole page is done as an SVG image you can save that instead.

Comment: How would you like to host it? This part is not clear to me. You tagged it with PHP and SQL, but neither would explain what you want to do with this image on the server.

Comment: He's right. It's not a PNG even though it has the `.png` extension; it's a SVG. It works because most browsers ignore file extensions and rely on [MIME sniffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing) or the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header. And if you right-click the image and select "View page source", you'll see how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 2 PNG file with animation and encode with base64. You can use base64 decode image service to convert it back to PNG like this : [image]

And if you want serve your PNG file like this, just simple use PHP base64 encoder like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php base64_encode($image) ?>">
```

ABOUT PNG FILE TYPE IN URL

This is fake URL, not the real file type. The real file type maybe PHP. You can do like this many way like Laravel Route and just simple htaccess rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.png
```

Comment: Edited answer to explain your question about file type.

Comment: thank you for the help. I did a simple html page that support what i want. i create a gif image in photoshop and render as video in .png sequence. with this i has able to create a .png with animation like my exemple page: http://www.crisxsilva.com.br/filewarez/teste.html | now, you know how i convert my page for a teste.png such "AGK111112.png" example? i want to load my page in a forum bbcode but im not able to do with an .html file

Comment: so i just need rewrite my .htaccess in root folder such your example then the file "teste.html" will work in "teste.png"?

Comment: I got it! thank you very mutch with your help and examples!